# Add element conditional between group of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, group

I have the following code, to make a new array.

```js
const datos = [{
        "id": "re_alt_sr",
        "quantity": 345,
        "selectable": false
      },
      {
        "id": "re_alt_gen",
        "quantity": 740,
        "selectable": true
      },
      {
        "id": "re2_alw_gen2",
        "quantity": 40,
        "selectable": true
      },
      {
        "id": "re_st_w_show",
        "quantity": 1,
        "selectable": true
      }]
var list = [];
for (const item of datos) {
  list.push({
    name: item.id,
    value: item.quantity,
    is: item.selectable
  })
}

console.log(list)
```

But I want to add a new element among which are selectable.

```json
{"name": "default", "value": 0, "status": true}
```

Leaving something like this:

```json
[
    {"name": "re_alt_sr", "value": 345, "is": false },
    {"name": "re2_alw_gen2","value": 40,"is": true },
    {"name": "default", "value": 0, "status": true},
    {"name": "re_alt_gen", "value": 740, "is": true},
    {"name": "default", "value": 0, "status": true},
    {"name": "re_st_w_show", "value": 1, "is": true}
]
```

Point to clarify: *as you think: unselectables are one group and SI-selectables is another.
There will be other arrays that are all "unselectable" so you don't need to add anything to them.*

Comment: Have you tried using an `if` statement for the conditions you require?

Comment: in that case the new element would be added twice. I only need it the first time. You could say that it is to separate the 2 types of selectable (is)

Comment: From the answers already given, you could use those techniques to modify your existing code on the requirements that have changed on your end. As it stands now, it is not clear what your new requirements are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SOLUTION stays close to your existing code by employing an `if` statement to get the *"new element between those that are not selectable and those that are."*.

Essentially what it does is keep track of the previous item's selectable state, and when a difference is detected, it inserts the new element.

```js
const datos = [{
        "id": "re_alt_sr",
        "quantity": 345,
        "selectable": false
      },
      {
        "id": "re_alt_gen",
        "quantity": 740,
        "selectable": true
      },
      {
        "id": "re_st_w_show",
        "quantity": 1,
        "selectable": true
      }]
var list = [];

// Var to track of previous item's selectable state
var previousSelectableState = null; 

for (const item of datos) {
    
    
    // NEW CODE BEGIN
    if ( previousSelectableState !== null) {
        // Not at first item    
        
        if (previousSelectableState !== item.selectable ) {
            // Previous item selectable differs from this one
        
            list.push( {"id": "default", "quantity": 0, "status": true} );
        }
    }
    
    previousSelectableState = item.selectable; // for next iteration
    // NEW CODE END
    
    list.push({
        name: item.id,
        value: item.quantity,
        is: item.selectable
    })

}

console.log(list)
```

Comment: looks excellent. But it seems from where I'm getting the data it tells me which way it should actually go between the selectables.

There will be a list containing up to 8 selectable items.
I'll edit my question for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), which is a useful function that iterates through an array, and passes a value from each iteration to the next.

```js
const datos = [{"id": "re_alt_sr","quantity": 345,"selectable": false},{"id": "re_alt_gen","quantity": 740,"selectable": true},{"id": "re_st_w_show","quantity": 1,"selectable": true}];

const list = datos.reduce((acc, val) => {
  // Can't use index here because we may have already 
  // injected extra items into array. So we use length instead
  const prev = acc[acc.length - 1];
  return prev && prev.selectable !== val.selectable ?
    [
      ...acc,
      {"id": "default", "quantity": 0, "status": true},
      val
    ] : 
    [...acc, val];
},[]);

console.log(list)
```

Comment: I will try. But it seems that where I'm getting the data from tells me which direction it should go between the selectables. There will be a list containing up to 8 selectable items. I will edit my question for better understanding.